# R console output spills into LaTeX when using rgdal

Tags: floats, knitr

I can't avoid the R console output from spilling into the `LaTeX` document compiled by `knitr`.

Please consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<Map, dev='jpeg', dpi=300, fig.cap='Italy', fig.env='figure',message=FALSE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
library(rgdal)

# Download shape file from here: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip
shape_file = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"

# Build map
map <- readOGR(shape_file, layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3")

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey")


@ 

\end{document}
```

When I `knit()` it I get in the `.tex` document as picture

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{verbatim}
## OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
## Source: "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp", layer: "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3"
## with 246 features and 11 fields
## Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}\begin{figure}[]

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/Map} \caption[Italy]{Italy\label{fig:Map}}
\end{figure}


\end{knitrout}
```

Why the options `message=FALSE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,error=FALSE` don't kick in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `verbose=FALSE` option for `readOGR`. I think it just not an `R` output, but an output for some compiled library or program that `rgdal` is using internally.